# Use Inline CSS to apply USD Currency Format within HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a regularly published webcast of sales data and am struggling to properly format the sales totals in USD currency format ($ symbol, thousands comma separator, 2 decimal places). The webcast is controlled using the below file. I am a total HTML & CSS newbie, so appreciate any specific guidance. I have been researching and testing but just need any help or ideas- THANK YOU!

Tried so far:
Creating a SPAN for this such as:
     
      .dollars:before {content:'$';}

Also:
       
            {Source}
            {SalesAmount}

I also tried this but couldn't get it working.
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?43459-CSS-number-formatting
and

```html
<style type='text/css'>
 caption.mytable
 {
  background-color:99CCFF;
  color:black;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:336699;
  text-align:center;
 }

 table.mytable
  { 
  font-family:Tahoma;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  font-size:10pt;
  background-color:white;
  width:100%;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:336699;
  border-width:1px;
 }

 th.mytable
 {
  font-size:8pt;
  color:black;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
 }

 tr.mytable
 { 
 }

 td.mytable
 {  
  font-size:8pt;
  background-color:white;
  color:black;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:cccccc;
  text-align:left;
  padding:3px;
 }
</style>

<table class='mytable'>
 <caption class="mytable">{EVENT_DESCRIPTION_COLOR} as of {EVENT_DATE}</caption>
 <thead>
  <tr class='mytable'>
   <th class='mytable'>Source Type</th>
   <th class='mytable'>Sales Amount</th>
  </tr>
 </thead> 
 <tbody>
  
  <tr class='mytable'>
   <td class='mytable'>{Source}</td>
   <td class='mytable'>{SalesAmount}</td>
  </tr>
  
 </tbody>
</table>
<style type='text/css'>
 caption.mytable
 {
  background-color:99CCFF;
  color:black;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:336699;
  text-align:center;
 }

 table.mytable
  { 
  font-family:Tahoma;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  font-size:10pt;
  background-color:white;
  width:100%;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:336699;
  border-width:1px;
 }

 th.mytable
 {
  font-size:8pt;
  color:black;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
 }

 tr.mytable
 { 
 }

 td.mytable
 {  
  font-size:8pt;
  background-color:white;
  color:black;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:cccccc;
  text-align:left;
  padding:3px;
 }
</style>

<table class='mytable'>
 <caption class="mytable">{EVENT_DESCRIPTION_COLOR} as of {EVENT_DATE}</caption>
 <thead>
  <tr class='mytable'>
   <th class='mytable'>Source Type</th>
   <th class='mytable'>Sales Amount</th>
  </tr>
 </thead> 
 <tbody>
  
  <tr class='mytable'>
   <td class='mytable'>{Source}</td>
   <td class='mytable'>{SalesAmount}</td>
  </tr>
  
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I dont think css can do that much (changing decimal separator/number of decimal points). For that you will need to do something server side or some js to modify the text.

Comment: You would need Javascript to parse the text content and add the comma's and if you are going to do that you might as well add the dollar symbol at the same time.

Comment: It's better if the values came converted by server-side. With PHP for example is better than javascript, and it avoid to low performance in client-side. With php, with a simple `number_format(".", ",")` it's fine

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude what about the thousand separators and decimal places

Comment: I tell that server side is better to convert numbers (separators, decimal places, etc). In my example I write in PHP, but there are tons of languages.

Comment: @litelite can you tell any solutions or read carefully that we write?

Comment: @Paulie_D Do you know how to do that? If I want to use JavaScript to handle the number formatting, can I add JavaScript to my existing file?

Answer (score 8):

Your own solution works. Check this:

```css
.dollars:before {
  content: "$";
}
.euros:after {
  content: "€";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td class='mytable'><span class="dollars">788.99</span></td></tr>
  <tr><td class='mytable'><span class="euros">788.99</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

### EDIT

You can use this function (from http://phpjs.org ) that allows to control fine your numbers:

```js
function number_format(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {

  number = (number + '')
    .replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '');
  var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
    prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
    sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
    dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
    s = '',
    toFixedFix = function(n, prec) {
      var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
      return '' + (Math.round(n * k) / k)
        .toFixed(prec);
    };
  // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
  s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n))
    .split('.');
  if (s[0].length > 3) {
    s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
  }
  if ((s[1] || '')
    .length < prec) {
    s[1] = s[1] || '';
    s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1)
      .join('0');
  }
  return s.join(dec);
}

alert(number_format(8277267283832.289877, 2, ".",","));


  //   example 1: number_format(1234.56);
  //   returns 1: '1,235'
  //   example 2: number_format(1234.56, 2, ',', ' ');
  //   returns 2: '1 234,56'
  //   example 3: number_format(1234.5678, 2, '.', '');
  //   returns 3: '1234.57'
  //   example 4: number_format(67, 2, ',', '.');
  //   returns 4: '67,00'
  //   example 5: number_format(1000);
  //   returns 5: '1,000'
  //   example 6: number_format(67.311, 2);
  //   returns 6: '67.31'
  //   example 7: number_format(1000.55, 1);
  //   returns 7: '1,000.6'
  //   example 8: number_format(67000, 5, ',', '.');
  //   returns 8: '67.000,00000'
  //   example 9: number_format(0.9, 0);
  //   returns 9: '1'
  //  example 10: number_format('1.20', 2);
  //  returns 10: '1.20'
  //  example 11: number_format('1.20', 4);
  //  returns 11: '1.2000'
  //  example 12: number_format('1.2000', 3);
  //  returns 12: '1.200'
  //  example 13: number_format('1 000,50', 2, '.', ' ');
  //  returns 13: '100 050.00'
  //  example 14: number_format(1e-8, 8, '.', '');
  //  returns 14: '0.00000001'
```

Comment: I think his problem is more than adding a $/€ sign, but also the number of decimal places/ decimal separator

Comment: That task is impossible with CSS. However, in his code is not present nothing about the symbol.

Comment: in his question, he ask about _($ symbol, thousands comma separator, 2 decimal places)_ it do is true that there is nothing for the $ sign in his code, but there is more to his problem than that.

Comment: UGH just realized this works in Chrome but not IE (at least IE 10 which I'm using). Thanks @MarcosPérezGude for the sanity check. So if the other pieces (comma separating the thousands, and rounding to the nearest penny) are not possible in CSS/HTML, what is the best way to achieve them? I'd like to use something like this css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/format-currency/   but am not sure how to actually insert it or properly link to it. Others might know??

Comment: @SQLLearner don't worry, this code works in IE, Chrome, Firefox, iOS and Android. Your problem is the number formatting

Comment: SQLLearner are you using a server-side language, like PHP, Java, .NET, etc?

Comment: a complete php code must be : `$number = 98889099.28388; $formatted = number_format($number, 2, ".", ",");` . With this you have 2 decimals, thousand comma separated, decimals dotted separated. What more you need?

Comment: I recommend you PHPJs library. It contains functions of php in javascript, that it's very very useful. I will edit my answer with that

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude thanks so much for your ideas. I'm not sure about what Server-side language is used but I think that .NET or Java may be involved. There is a third-party application that creates the webpage from my file, so I'm not sure how to control it.

Comment: I edit my answer with a javascript function to allows you to control the numbers without a server-side script. But it's better performance if the values comes formatted from server.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude you are awesome. So I just add the function to my HTML file? At the top? Or? Sorry I do not know!